# How to use this js svg parser to change the path's decimal places in an svg file or element to n decimals?

Tags: javascript, math, svg, raphael, snap.svg

There is [this](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/scripts/svg-parser.js) svg parser that does few svg optimization including changing an svg path's decimal places. if you use snap svg and make a path element :

```
var paper = Snap("100%","100%").attr({"viewbox":"0,0,500,600"});
var pth = paper.path("M89.86111111111111,140.00000000000003C89.30555555555556,138.61111111111114,88.61111111111111,137.6388888888889,87.63888888888889,136.94444444444446C86.66666666666667,136.25000000000003,85.55555555555556,135.97222222222223,84.58333333333334,135.97222222222223C83.33333333333334,135.97222222222223,82.22222222222223,136.25000000000003,81.38888888888889,136.80555555555557C80.55555555555556,137.36111111111114,79.86111111111111,138.19444444444446,79.30555555555556,139.16666666666669C78.75,140.1388888888889,78.33333333333333,141.25000000000003,78.05555555555556,142.50000000000003C77.77777777777777,143.75000000000003,77.77777777777777,145.00000000000003,77.77777777777777,146.25000000000003C77.77777777777777,147.6388888888889,77.91666666666667,148.8888888888889,78.19444444444444,150.1388888888889C78.47222222222223,151.3888888888889,79.02777777777777,152.50000000000003,79.58333333333333,153.47222222222223C80.13888888888889,154.44444444444446,80.83333333333334,155.1388888888889,81.66666666666667,155.69444444444446C82.5,156.25000000000003,83.61111111111111,156.5277777777778,84.72222222222223,156.5277777777778C86.11111111111111,156.5277777777778,87.22222222222223,155.97222222222223,88.05555555555556,155.1388888888889C88.88888888888889,154.30555555555557,89.44444444444444,153.33333333333334,89.86111111111111,152.36111111111114M71.11111111111111,146.25000000000003C71.11111111111111,148.8888888888889,71.38888888888889,151.3888888888889,72.08333333333333,153.61111111111114C72.77777777777777,155.83333333333334,73.75,157.7777777777778,75,159.30555555555557C76.25,160.83333333333334,77.5,162.08333333333334,79.16666666666667,162.91666666666669C80.69444444444444,163.75000000000003,82.36111111111111,164.30555555555557,84.16666666666667,164.30555555555557C85.83333333333334,164.30555555555557,87.63888888888889,163.8888888888889,89.16666666666667,163.05555555555557C90.69444444444444,162.22222222222223,91.94444444444444,160.97222222222223,93.19444444444444,159.44444444444446C94.44444444444444,157.91666666666669,95.41666666666667,155.97222222222223,96.11111111111111,153.75000000000003C96.80555555555556,151.5277777777778,97.22222222222223,149.0277777777778,97.22222222222223,146.25000000000003C97.22222222222223,143.75000000000003,96.94444444444444,141.3888888888889,96.25,139.30555555555557C95.55555555555556,137.22222222222223,94.72222222222223,135.2777777777778,93.47222222222223,133.61111111111114C92.22222222222223,131.94444444444446,90.83333333333334,130.83333333333334,89.30555555555556,129.86111111111114C87.77777777777777,128.8888888888889,85.97222222222223,128.47222222222223,84.16666666666667,128.47222222222223C82.36111111111111,128.47222222222223,80.69444444444444,128.8888888888889,79.02777777777777,129.86111111111114C77.36111111111111,130.83333333333334,76.11111111111111,131.94444444444446,74.86111111111111,133.61111111111114C73.61111111111111,135.2777777777778,72.77777777777777,137.08333333333334,72.08333333333333,139.30555555555557C71.38888888888889,141.5277777777778,71.11111111111111,143.75000000000003,71.11111111111111,146.25000000000003");
console.log(pth.toString());
```

How to reduce those decimal places to n decimal places either using the linked svg parser above or any other way using js please?

**Update:**
Thank you @Ian. Using your code, How can we use the below code to round if there is any decimals?:

```
 if (dec || dec === 0)
    {
      if (dec > 1) dec = 1;
      else if (dec < 0) dec = 0;
    }
    else dec = false;

    function r(num)
    {
if (dec !== false) return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
      else return num;
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, do you know if IE display this as the same format ? Iirc I think Ie sometimes displays paths slightly differently, but I'm not sure if that passes on to toString(), but may be worth checking. Otherwise I was wondering if you could just use some regex over the string.

Comment: Btw, looking at the docs of http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/svg-optimiser by the same author (not quite sure if its exactly the same thing), he says that it has decimal place support for svg paths.

Comment: Thank you @Ian, I haven't checked the path with ie yet, but that is s good thing to know. And that program is in Python but he has the js version of that here: http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor , but I want to use only that part of his js code related to decimals places not all the svg optimization he has on that file. any Idea how to trim down to that minimum please?

Comment: Out of interest, how essential is proper rounding...I'm just wondering if this regex would work.. http://jsfiddle.net/rbkruj7p/1/ it doesn't round though, just outputs to 2 places.

Comment: Thank you @Ian. That is cool. How can we use the below code to round  if there is any decimals?: if (dec || dec === 0)
    {
      if (dec > 1) dec = 1;
      else if (dec < 0) dec = 0;
    }
    else dec = false;
 
    function r(num)
    {
      if (dec !== false) return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
      else return num;
    }

Comment: @Ian, Or can we make or turn that to a snap plugin to do the decimals for an svg file or path element?!

Comment: An alternative (shortened) rounding function.  Optionally specify the number of digits precision, otherwise it defaults to 2.  `function R(n,p=2){return Math.round(n*10**p)/10**p}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some regex like this...I think this will round as well as cut off...

```
var newstring = string.replace(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/g, function(x){ return (+x).toFixed(2)  });
```

Then you can apply that whereever, in a paths d attribute etc

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbkruj7p/3/)

Comment: Thank you @Ian, That is great! Can you apply that to an svg file that has been loaded to a snap paper?

Comment: Yes, you can just do something like el.attr({ d: trimString( el.attr('d') ) }) for the path, assuming the above is a function called trimString or whatever.

Comment: And if the element is snap paper it can be like: paper.attr({d: trimString(paper.attr('d')) }): ?!

Comment: A paper wouldn't have a d attribute, only a path would. You could do a paper.selectAll('path').forEach( function(el) { el.trim() } ), with a plugin or trim(el) without, but basically you need to get all the paths, or even every element and check if its got a d attribute or something.

Comment: Thank you @Ian. I am trying to make a snap plugin but I get some errors and here I have asked another question for that. could you please check that for me?!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293267/what-is-wrong-with-this-snap-svg-plugin

Comment: A quick question @Ian here: If I wanted to use the above code like this: string.replace(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/g, function(x){ return (+x).toFixed(2)  }); it wouldn't work! I want to change the same path instead of making new paths. is that because of memory conflict and problems?!

Comment: Not quite sure of the question, it isn't creating a new path. It is creating a new string variable. You then update an attribute with the new string. You could do something like  el.attr({ d: el.attr('d').replace(...... etc probably though just to shorten the code a bit (but may make it a harder to read/debug)

Comment: Thank you @Ian, here I clarify my question: Without making a new string, how can I change the d attr of the paths of an element to reflect on the paper? I am trying this but doesn't work: pthstr.attr({ d: pthstr.attr('d').replace(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/g, function(x){ return (+x).toFixed(2)  }) });

Comment: The other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293267/what-is-wrong-with-this-snap-svg-plugin has it working this way....so use that. If its still not working, post another question with a jsfiddle is probably best way as you don't have enough points to chat in here yet.

Comment: Thank you @Ian.yes the plugin works great just I wanted to try without that plugin. I found a way around for it, that works but I just wanted to make it shorter! : var pthstr = textpaths.toString();
var newstr = pthstr.replace(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/g, function(x){ return (+x).toFixed(2)  });
textpaths.remove();
var pth = paper.path(newstr).attr({'fill' : 'none', 'stroke' : 'blue'});